# reference a filename in vi

Tags: c++, vim

Sometimes I run **make** directly from the vim command line. However,  sometimes I would just like to build one file currently being edited: `!g++ filename.cpp` . Is there a shortcut to reference the file without having to type it..?

Guys, I DO NOT want to use make at all. all I want to do is to build it from vi's command line, using g++/gcc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `%` to reference the current file
so:

```
:!g++ %
```

Answer (score 2):

in VIM "%:p" stands for the current file.

try "!g++ %:p"

Comment: It expand to the full path from root. I got used to it because I was typing something that lose the root. Its not required here, I typed the response fast, but Peter answer is the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to refer to the filename you are working on with the extension substituted with .o:

```
%r.o
```

Your filename.cpp becomes filename.o which is useful if you put something like this in your .vimrc.:

```
set makeprg=gmake\ %:r.o
```

That way you can just do this in vim and it will then launch the command declared using makeprg on the current file:

```
:make
```

Comment: Can you explain the colon in '%:r.o' (or the absence of the colon previously)?

Comment: see `:help filename-modifiers`

Answer (score 2):

If your make program is actually GNU make, just execute:

```
:make %<
```

If you want to add flags like -Wall or -pedantic then just set $CFLAG (for compiling C files, or $CPPFLAGS for C++ files), or if you want to specify libraries then set $LDFLAGS from vim.

```
:h :make
:h %<
```

EDIT:
Unlike plain calls to :!gcc, this solution is compatible with the quickfix mode (:h quickfix), and it does not require to change &makeprg to 'g++ $CPPFLAGS -o $* $*.cpp $LDFLAGS'.

NB:

- No need to write any makefile to take advantage of GNU-make.
- And even if you have one Makefile, and as long as you don't mess with the default implicit rules, this solution will also work!

Comment: I DO NOT want to use make at all. all I want to do is to build it from using g++/gcc

Comment: You missed the point there is no need to write any makefile, and that GNU-make will call gcc or g++ by himself without us to tell him to do so.

Comment: What will make %< generate? a.out or filename (executable)?  what is the point of < ?  thanks.

Comment: %< is % without the extension. It tells make to generate the executable with no extension (unless under windows as it is implicit there)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the shortcut is %.

You can bind the whole thing to one key by putting the following in your .vimrc file:

```
map <F9> :!gcc %<CR>
```